# Nginx as load balancer with 75% and 25% weighted routing

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to Nginx. I have two servers serverA and serverB. I want a 75% request to go to serverA and rest 25% requests to serverB. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use nginx weighted routing:

```
stream { 
    upstream stream_backend { 
        server srv1.example.com weight=75;
        server srv2.example.com weight=25; 
    } 
    server { 
        listen 80; 
        proxy_pass stream_backend; 
    } 
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_weighted_load_balancing

Comment: @KarmveerSingh was my answer helpful? let me know if not, id like to help